# NetworkManager crashing

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, systemd, wicd

**When did the problem start:**

I recently installed the package wicd, and after I did this, I started having problems with my WiFi connection. I never directly changed any configuration files or anything like that, all I did was start the wicd daemon and used wicd-curses and wicd-client, both front ends to operate wicd.

**Description of the problem:**

Here is the problem. Whenever I leave my computer unattended for a brief amount of time and come back, the WiFi completely stops working. I cannot reconnect, and the only thing that fixes this is rebooting the computer.

**What I have tried**

I have tried restarting the service NetworkManager, and restarting the daemon 'networking.service', neither of these actions work. I have also tried purging NetworkManager, auto-removing, and reinstalling it, as well as purging wicd, and all wicd front ends. Needless to say, none of these actions have worked.

**Further description of the problem**

The service 'networking.service' is always failed. Whenever I boot the system, it fails immediantly. This is the only service that is not working. Here is the output of the systemctl command.

```
 $ systemctl status networking.service
● networking.service - Raise network interfaces
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/networking.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2019-09-21 00:32:16 CDT; 20min ago
     Docs: man:interfaces(5)
  Process: 761 ExecStart=/sbin/ifup -a --read-environment (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 761 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

I don't know what I should do to solve this problem, if anyone has any suggestions, please share.
Thanks so much.

Comment: If it's not working - might it be better to remove it? hy did you need to install it in the first place?

Comment: I wanted to try wicd because I was thinking of switching to XFCE and apparently XFCE users typically use wicd. I have tried removing it, and I believe it is gone. I am not sure if it is or isn't, because when I apropos wicd, it returns all the wicd programs I supposedly removed. However, if I try running one of these, it says that it isn't there, so I therefore believe I have removed it.

Comment: For reverting to Network Manager review the following official documentation page https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WICD

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Gnome then it would seem that you don't actually  need to use XFCE and therefore it would perhaps be best to revert to Network Manager.

To do this, you need to follow these steps:

For Gnome / Unity

Open up a Terminal and execute the following commands:

```
Install NetworkManager:

    sudo apt-get install network-manager-gnome network-manager 
Then remove WICD:

    sudo apt-get remove wicd wicd-gtk
```

Restart your system. Confirm everything is working, then remove WICD config files:

```
    sudo dpkg --purge wicd wicd-gtk
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing -- I haven't had the problem since doing this. However, I do not know if this is just luck or not. After restarting, systemctl still shows that 'networking.service' fails. I'll post updates if WiFi stops working again.

Comment: @foobar You might find this thread about systemctl of help with the ongoing issue https://askubuntu.com/questions/1057347/having-a-real-problem-with-systemctl-networking